# Is there a way to instruct pytest to skip the module definition?

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way to tell `pytest` to mock out any `__init__.py`s, or otherwise skip them?

I have a python module with a global dependency that gets introduced via a Docker container. Here's an example:

```
/mymodule
  /__init__.py
  mymodule.py
  mymodule_test.py
```

`mymodule/__init__.py` looks like:

```
from .mymodule import mymodule
```

And `mymodule/mymodule.py` looks like:

```
import globalpackage

def mymodule():
  pass
```

Finally, we have a `Dockerfile` that looks like:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8
COPY /some/path/to/globalpackage /app/globalpackage
COPY mymodule /app
```

So that, at runtime, `globalpackage` is available as an import. I can't change this structure as it's used across our codebase.

The issue I'm running into is in trying to write a test for this module. It seems that pytest hits the module `__init__.py` before it hits any tests. This means I'm unable to mock or patch `globalpackage` (which doesn't exist when running `pytest` at the command line).

I can't for the life of me figure out a way of skipping over `__init__.py` in this scenario. Ideally I'd like to avoid modifying the src code, as that will lead to a massive refactor.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202355/pytest-cannot-mock-init-of-my-class) should answer your question

Comment: Your link refers to the `__init__ ` constructor on a class, doesn’t it? I’m asking about `__init__.py`  which defines a module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking a module import in pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43162722/8601760)